# How in Backbone.js I can know that model.fetch is sucsess (about event)?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, web

I have the model 'note' and the collection 'to_paste'.
I want to fetch 'to_paste' after my model 'note' was fetched successfully because in 'to_paste' I want to use some parameters from 'note'.

So, what's the event I should use?

I did the next things but I'm sure it's wrong (I just fetch collection in model success).

```
note.fetch({
  success: function (collection, note1) {
        var noteView = new Memo.Views.FullNote( {model: note}, {flag: 1 } );
        var to_paste = new Memo.Collections.NotebookList(); 
        to_paste.fetch({  
          success: function (collection) {
          var notebooks_to_paste = new Memo.Views.NotebookListToDelete( {collection: to_paste} );
          var notebook_id = note.get("notebook_id");    
          $('.example').html(notebooks_to_paste.render().el);   
        }
      });
      $('.content').html(noteView.render().el);
    }
  });
```

Comment: There is no such event. The only way is use `success` handler (as you do) or [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) object returned by `fetch`.

Comment: Why do you think it's wrong..?

Comment: What if I need three different models or more? Should I use the way as I do?

Comment: What you have done seems fine, if you want to use check "sync" event in backbonejs. if you have multiple models you can use jquery when/done to look code better

Comment: @EugeneMos You mean you want to fetch `to_paste` when many models are successfully fetched..? Are they in the same collection..? You should [edit] your question and make a clear problem statement